# See other answers in Low Quality Review

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts

When reviewing the Low Quality Posts, it'd be nice to see other answers.

For example: if there's an answer with just a link with no description, I'll edit it if it's the only answer, but if there's another answer with the same info, I'd just recommend for deletion (or hit Not Sure if it's borderline).

Comment: Isn't there a link that gets you to the entire post?

Comment: Open. In. New. Tab.

Comment: @Xaade I do that. It's annoying to have to do that on *every single question*.

Comment: @RobertHarvey There is. I have to use it every time.

Comment: @CajunLuke Well then, we could include the relevant info first, the rest of the question and answers next. And a google search on key terms in the question (that way, if someone answers to search google, and it only returns this question, we can downvote them from review page).

Comment: @Xaade That's pretty much what I was thinking - have the post in question, then the question (if the flagged post was an answer, just like it is now), then a list of all the other answers (if there are any). I also like your Google suggestion.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285526/show-other-answers-in-low-quality-review

Answer (score 1):

> if there's an answer with just a link with no description, I'll edit it if it's the only answer

If you can edit it, why not just do that? Surely that's preferable to deletion, *if* the link actually answers the question...

Also note that the review page *does* tell you whether or not there are other answers. You can certainly skip the check if there aren't.

Comment: But you need to look at the other answers to see if the response in the new answer differs or is similar to the others, if the former then  I will think how to improve the question

Comment: If the reviewer is deciding how best to use his/her time, it might be reasonable to determine that investigating the contents of the link, applying them to the question at hand, and writing a proper answer is not worth the time, when another answer already exists, containing all of the information that this effort would likely yield.